# SELECT 'RecordCode' FROM tbl_1 IF 'RecordCode' Exists in tbl_2

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run a query in MS Access to SELECT any record which already exists in a second table.

I'm going to be writing an UPDATE query to update my 'Master' data-set from a report, but I would like to construct this SELECT query first to make sure I am updating the correct records.

Here is what I have written so far:

```sql
SELECT RecordCode
FROM tbl_Master
WHERE tbl_Master!RecordCode = tbl_Update!RecordCode;
```

When I run this query, I get an 'Enter Parameter Value' message box appear for the **tbl_Update!OfficeCode**.

Please can you help me get this query working as expected?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to `JOIN tbl_Update ON tbl_Master!RecordCode = tbl_Update!RecordCode` and remove the `Where` clause. Unless you need to target other rows specifically.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - Thank you for your response.  Do you agree it should be INNER JOIN?

Comment: From your description and query. You want to update only the records that match. Try the `LEFT JOIN` and see what you get.

Comment: I do SQL Server and if you just put `JOIN` it is implied as `INNER JOIN`. :-)

Comment: INNER JOIN seems to work better than LEFT JOIN.  Thanks very much for your help @WEI_DBA :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @WEI_DBA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851536/select-recordcode-from-tbl-1-if-recordcode-exists-in-tbl-2?noredirect=1#comment98364959_55851536), this solution works perfectly for my requirements.

```sql
SELECT RecordCode
FROM tbl_Master
INNER JOIN tbl_Update ON tbl_Master!RecordCode = tbl_Update!RecordCode;
```